# Get landmark coordinates near the map centre

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary

Using the windows phone 8 map control I want to be able to collect a list of all the landmarks/points of interest within a radius of a given point (mainly my map centre). I have looked at other questions on this site but they are either geared toward Android or suggestions I tried that did not pan out. I tried online but there does not seem to be a definitive method for achieving this on windows phone 8.

Does anyone know of a service/api, that has been shown to work in the method described above, that I could leverage to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in Windows Phone 8 Map control. You have to set LandmarksEnabled property of the map control to true. Here it is:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.maps.controls.map.landmarksenabled%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thank you. I have used this to show me the landmarks on the map. What I need though is to be able to get a list of coordinates to those landmarks.